# Zero values being read-in as missing values in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to trace through a sheet and highlight cells that come back as blank values or 0 values (or "NaN") values.  I wrote a nested for loop to do this for me, however, I am seeing a weird item.

The cell in question should change to red if the value equals 0.  When I run my macro, however, the end result is that all the cells that pass the `if statement` conditions end as yellow, even if 0.  Perhaps VBA reads blank cells as 0, or the cells are not truly blank? Have I made a mistake, or am I incorrect on the logic of VBA?

```
    'i is for the columns
For i = 2 To 4 'lastColumn

    totalCounter = 0
    outageCounter = 0
    missingCounter = 0

    'j is for the rows
    For j = 6 To lastRow

        'highlight if production outage
        If mainSheet.Cells(j, i).Value = 0 Then
            mainSheet.Cells(j, i).Interior.Color = vbRed
            outageCounter = outageCounter + 1
        End If

        'highlight if comm outage
        If mainSheet.Cells(j, i).Value = "" Or mainSheet.Cells(j, i).Value = "NaN" Then
            mainSheet.Cells(j, i).Interior.Color = vbYellow
            missingCounter = missingCounter + 1
        End If

        totalCounter = totalCounter + 1

    Next j

    mainSheet.Cells(lastRow + 2, i).Value = missingCounter
    mainSheet.Cells(lastRow + 3, i).Value = outageCounter
    mainSheet.Cells(lastRow + 4, i).Value = totalCounter
```

Comment: I believe you are correct--your initial `IF` will be true even when the value in the cell is blank.

Comment: Curious: What is "NaN" as you're using it? AFAIK, Excel doesn't have a NaN value (as in "not a number"), unless your data just have the string "NaN" in there.

Comment: Your code will set empty cells, cells containing `""`, and cells containing `"NaN"` to yellow (after first changing empty cells to red for a very short time).  But there is no reason why your code should be changing cells containing `0` to be yellow as you say in your question ("all the cells that pass the if statement conditions end as yellow, even if 0").  Are you 100% certain that cells containing a `0` end up as yellow?!?

Comment: @YowE3K I think I can answer for the OP. When the cell has nothing in it, `.Value` will match either 0 or "" in the `If` statements, so, yes, both conditions will be satisfied.

Comment: @vknowles - but that doesn't explain how a `0` ends up yellow - just why an empty cell ends up yellow (after being red for a short time).

Comment: @YowE3K - Good point. Probably the OP described it incorrectly. My mistake.

Comment: @vknowles - I did wonder whether that was a mistake in the question, but even the title is `Zero values being read-in as missing values in VBA` which seems to mean that the problem is with cells containing `0`, not with empty cells.

Comment: Is it possible that you have a cell format that displays text using a format of `\0`?  Perhaps so that you can have a formula calculate an empty string but then is displayed as a `0`?  That would cause those cells to be coloured yellow instead of red, even though it looks like the cells are `0`.

Comment: @vknowles  I am working with data imported from our db, so the NaN values come in as strings to excel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Excel the default value of an empty cell is zero, so you need to check there's actually some content before checking for zero:

```
 Dim c As Range

 For j = 6 To lastRow

    Set c = mainSheet.Cells(j, i)

    'highlight if production outage
    If Len(c.Value) > 0 And c.Value = 0 Then
        c.Interior.Color = vbRed
        outageCounter = outageCounter + 1
    End If

    'highlight if comm outage
    If c.Value = "" Or c.Value = "NaN" Then
        c.Interior.Color = vbYellow
        missingCounter = missingCounter + 1
    End If

    totalCounter = totalCounter + 1

Next j
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `Text` property and check it against `0` ("production outage") and "" or "NaN" ("comm outage")

you can also use some `With - End With` to reduce typing and memory accesses

```
With mainSheet
    For i = 2 To 4 'lastColumn

        totalCounter = 0
        outageCounter = 0
        missingCounter = 0

        'j is for the rows
        For j = 6 To lastrow

            With .Cells(j, i)
                Select Case .Text
                    Case 0
                        'highlight if production outage
                        .Interior.Color = vbRed
                        outageCounter = outageCounter + 1

                    Case "", "NaN"
                        'highlight if comm outage
                        .Interior.Color = vbYellow
                        missingCounter = missingCounter + 1
                End Select

                totalCounter = totalCounter + 1
            End With
        Next j

        .Cells(lastrow + 2, i).value = missingCounter
        .Cells(lastrow + 3, i).value = outageCounter
        .Cells(lastrow + 4, i).value = totalCounter
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: I like this because it takes advantage of one property that distinguishes between empty and 0 rather than having to do two tests (length and value).